# Loading message for slow downloadhandler()

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to ask if there is a way to display a loading message before the file is finally downloaded in my shiny app. My original dataset is big and I guess this is the reason for this delay. Below I attach a toy example in case someone can apply the reuested solution on this.

```
#ui.r
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have implemented a solution based on your code. What you need to do is add a progress bar inside your `downloadhandler()`.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(



# App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),

      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      tableOutput("table")

    )

  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      shiny::withProgress(
        message = paste0("Downloading", input$dataset, " Data"),
        value = 0,
        {
          shiny::incProgress(1/10)
          Sys.sleep(1)
          shiny::incProgress(5/10)
          write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
      )
    }
  )

}
shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can tailor this solution to your requirements (customize message, add loop etc). I hope this helps :-)

Comment: sure great answer

Comment: Hi, does the time of loading needs to be estimated first, can it be customized? For example, for big data sets, we set 10s and small data sets, we set 1s?

Comment: I just notice that the download bar does not appear as soon as you press the button. it still needs to wait until the data got retrieved and then show the bar, And the bar's process time doesn't reflect on the actual time of the data retrieving